# Expire mongoose document after 1 minute

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I want to remove the document after one minute when it was created. I'm trying to use `expireAfterSeconds` but I probably doing it incorrectly. I probably need to use `createIndex` at first?

This is the line that I have right now :

`TempFight.findOne({code: fight.code}, { expireAfterSeconds: 5 } )`

I also have `createdAt` field in DB

Comment: That is very well documented: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to create index with `expireAfterSeconds` ex. `db.collectionName.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 } )`
Then insert document with `createdAt` ex. `db.collectionName.insert({"createdAt": new Date()})`. After this you documents will be deleted during 2m, because job is working everi minute.